# Do i need Special permission for Accessing Settings.System Class

Tags: java, android

I am using Settings.System class and want to display given parameter of my Android device.

```
AIRPLANE_MODE_ON: null
AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS: null
AUTO_TIME: null
FONT_SCALE: null
HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED: null
MODE_RINGER: null
MODE_RINGER_STREAMS_AFFECTED: null
MUTE_STREAMS_AFFECTED: null
NOTIFICATION_SOUND: null
RINGTONE: null
SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS: null
SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE: null
SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT: null
STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN: null
```

It shows every parameter to be null. Below is my part of code:

```
Log.d("Setting",Settings.Secure.getString(mcontex.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON.toString())); 
Log.d("Setting",Settings.Secure.getString(mcontex.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS.toString()))
```

Any Suggestion, Welcome..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to put the device in or out of airplane mode, the application must have WRITE_SETTINGS user permissions. This permission allows an application to read or write the system settings that include airplane mode. To request WRITE_SETTINGS add the  element to the Android Manifest file as demonstrated [here](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-airplane-mode/)